# Will Bodmas and Pemdas always yield the same results?

Tags: arithmetic

Will Bodmas and Pemdas always yield the same results?  The difference is in the order of execution of division and multiplication.

Comment: It’s difficult to say.

Comment: The position of the letters "D" and "M" do not mean "do this first." The order of operations say "multiplication and division from left to right in the order in which they appear."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they give the same results:
An easy way to understand this fact is to think of division simply as multiplication by the reciprocal. When you "divide" you are only doing an other multiplication.

Comment: Obviously this also applies to subtraction, which is by definition the addition for the opposite element.